# Visual studio does not run while web.config visible attribute set to false

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, csproj

I wanted to hide my web.config file using csproj but project won't debug even if web.config is included

```
<Content Include="web.config">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</Content>
```

this hides the web.config file but Visual studio does not recognize it even if its set to be included in project ? How can i fix this

Also i realised that you can hide sub config files and project runs perfectly but not the main config file, should not this just 'hide' the file ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#content

According to microsoft documentation this attribute only hides files.

Comment: What is your intention for hiding web.config?

Comment: because i want to see a clean project ? i want to hide .config files so i can focus on my pages etc. I hided everything except web.config file

Comment: I see, but for that you can't hide the main web.config because there are some config on it tht is use at runtime or on debugging.